# I'm using amazon mws to Product Feed Submission and returns id and success message,but i'm not able to find where its located in sellercentral?

Tags: amazon-web-services, submit, feed, product

I'm Submitting the below feed and geeting the submit feed id by getFeedSubmissionId().

But The product is not appearing in the sellers site. please help me in this regards.

feed :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>**********</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>RO7WA11930KB1CASB</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>EAN</Type>
                <Value>$ean</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <LaunchDate>$sDate</LaunchDate>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>$title</Title>
                <Brand>$mid</Brand>
                <Description>$desc</Description>    
                <MSRP currency="EUR">$price</MSRP>
                <Manufacturer>$mid</Manufacturer>
                <ItemType>stilhund</ItemType>
                <ItemPackageQuantity>$stock</ItemPackageQuantity>
                <RecommendedBrowseNode>12950661</RecommendedBrowseNode> 
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Health>
                    <ProductType>
                        <HealthMisc>
                            <Material>Stilhund Products</Material>
                        </HealthMisc>
                    </ProductType>
                </Health>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can find it with "GetFeedSubmissionResult" api where you pass your "FeedSubmissionId" and get the status of your submitted feed.